# Connecting SAP HANA DB from powershell

Tags: powershell, odbc, powershell-2.0, oledbconnection, hana

I am using the following Power Shell code to connect to a HANA instance from a host where HANA Client is installed -

```
    function Get-OLEDBData ($connectstring, $sql) {
    $OLEDBConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectstring)
    $OLEDBConn.open()
    $readcmd = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($sql,$OLEDBConn)
    $readcmd.CommandTimeout = '300'
    $da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($readcmd)
    $dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable
    [void]$da.fill($dt)
    $OLEDBConn.close()
    return $dt
    }

    $hdbSqlCmd = "myquery"
    $hdbConnectionString = "Driver={HDBODBC};ServerNode=myserver:30015;UID=myuser;PWD=mypasswd;"
    Get-OLEDBData $hdbConnectionString $hdbSqlCmd**
```

But I get following error -

```
   New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'."
   At C:\myspace\hana_connect_1.ps1:5 char:27+    $OLEDBConn = New-Object <<<<  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectstring)
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object],        MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

When I change the connection string to Provider instead of Driver -

```
   $hdbConnectionString = "Provider={HDBODBC};ServerNode=myserver:30015;UID=myuser;PWD=mypasswd;"
```

I get below error -

```
   Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The '{HDBODBC}' provider is not registered on the local machine."
   At C:\myspace\hana_connect_1.ps1:6 char:19
   +    $OLEDBConn.open <<<< ()
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The error remains the same even if I change to 32 bit driver - HDBODBC32, saying HDBODBC32 is not registered.

I am now lost, any help somebody!!

Comment: You could try to create a `*.udl` file. For example `test.udl`. Open the file and try to insert your connection string there to validate its not a script issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks but data link does not contain HDBODBC as a driver. It contains SAP Hana MDX Provider which cannot be used for the type of queries I want to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SAP HANA ODBC driver is **not** an OLEDB driver.
Therefore you have to use the ODBC API instead:

```
 function Get-ODBCBData ($connectstring, $sql) {
    $Conn = New-Object System.Data.odbc.ODBCconnection($connectstring)
    $Conn.open()
    $readcmd = New-Object system.Data.odbc.ODBCCommand($sql,$Conn)
    $readcmd.CommandTimeout = '300'
    ...
    $hdbConnectionString = "Driver={HDBODBC};ServerNode=myserver:30015;UID=myuser;PWD=mypasswd;"
    Get-ODBCBData $hdbConnectionString $hdbSqlCmd**
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed my issue been working on for days :(